# How to merge my access db while deploying setup exe

Tags: c#, ms-access

How to merge my access db while deploying setup exe.
I have created an exe and when install and launch exe I asked a path to create databse.This process is working
But I want to Create database when installing my exe,i.e., I want to merge my db file on deploying setup,like as dll is merged.

Comment: You can copy `.mdf` file with installer to an application folder.

Comment: Merge it with what?  At first I thought you meant merge a new schema with an existing database during an update but now I'm not so sure.  Do you simply mean that you want the data file to be part of your deployment package?  If so then it would help if we knew how that deployment package was created.  The fact that the application was written in C# is basically irrelevant.

Comment: I have an an access db file with tables and I want to merge that db with exe when I create a setup of my application,application used c#.

Comment: Are you saying you want to deploy your database with your application?

Comment: Yes I have to deploy my database with my application